# Trouble with form for nested models in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Okay, I have been banging my head against the wall for the past few hours trying to figure this out.  I have a rails ecommerce app... the store lists products objects, and when you add the product to your cart (another object) it is added by creating a line_item object.  When you are ready to checkout the line_items in your cart become an order.  At this point, I am trying to allow the customer to provide a page_url (an outside website the product/service will be used on) [via a form_for text_field] to each line_item.  To achieve this I created a new model called Page_url which belongs_to the order.  Here is what I have that has been failing miserably (I keep getting Controller errors "undefined method `page_url'"):

here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>

......

  <% @items.each do |item| %> 
   <td><a> Provide the URL the <%= item.product.title %> will be added to</a></td> 
    <div class="field">
     <%= f.fields_for @order, :page_url do |q| -%>
      <td> <%= q.label :page_url %>
      <%= q.text_field :page_url, size: 80 %>
    </td>
    <% end %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit t('.submit') %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

orders_controller:

```
 class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:new, :create]
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  skip_before_action :set_order, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]

  ......

   # GET /orders/new
  def new
   if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end
  @items = @cart.line_items
  @order = Order.new
  @page_urls = @order.page_urls
```

end

```
 .....

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:name, :address, :email, :pay_type,
                                :page_urls_attributes => [:page_url, :product_id,])
end
```

The Pages_url controller is the standard controller generated by Rails 4

Order.rb:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
has_many :page_urls, dependent: :destroy
# ...
validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES

accepts_nested_attributes_for :page_urls
```

Page_url.rb:

```
class PageUrl < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order
```

I appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use simple_form to create associations and it works great.

That way you can do `<%= f.association :page_urls %>`

They have great documentation, check here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form under Associations.

Also another point:

In your Order model, I would specify the class.

```
has_many :page_urls, dependent: :destroy, :class_name => PageUrl
```

And to create nested forms with simple_form see:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked like a charm. You're a life saver!